# Como puedo actualizar una tabla con un trigger after insert de esa misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

La cosa esta asi, se me pidio que en un triguer after insert se realice ciertas acciones, entre las cuales estan el actualizar un valor de esa misma tabla, y al hacerlo de forma literal me da un error logico por obvias razones, la idea es que solo se insertan los primeros cuatro valores en ventas y los dos restantes se calculen en el trigger, el ultimo se  queda;

Este es el codigo desarrollado de forma literal:

```
set @precio = 0;
set @cantidad = 0;

drop trigger bdtrpe05;
delimiter //;
create trigger bdtrpe05 after insert on ventas
for each row
begin
 select precio into @precio from articulos
  where idarticulo = new.idarticulo;
 select cantidad into @cantidad from ventas
  where idventa = new.idventa;
 update ventas set precio = @precio
   where idventa=new.idventa;
 update ventas set importe = (@precio * @cantidad)
   where idventa=new.idventa;
end;
//;
delimiter ;
```

Y las tablas son estas:

```
create table articulos
 (idarticulo int primary key auto_increment,
 nombre varchar(35),
 precio double,
 existencia int);         

create table ventas
 (idventa int,
 idarticulo int,
 fecha date,
 cantidad int,
 precio double,
 importe double);
```

Comment: MySQL no permite modificar la misma tabla que ha disparado el TRIGGER. Tendrías que recurrir a un procedimiento almacenado para eso, [ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878145/5587982) lanzando una transacción.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría mejor con un **before** insert:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger bdtrpe05 before insert on ventas
for each row
begin

 set new.precio =(select precio from articulos where idarticulo = new.idarticulo);
 set new.importe = (new.precio * new.cantidad);

end;
//
delimiter ;
```